# Windows 7 CD keys, are they interchangable?

Tags: windows-7, licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

*I am talking about during installation.* Using regular licensing, not volume licensing.

Amongst OSes of the same class, are CD keys interchangeable or are they *locked* to a specific subset of CDs?

In other words: If I have 10 legally purchased copies of Windows 7 Professional, can I throw out the discs for all but one? And all the CD keys will work?

**UPDATE**: How about for service packs (when they come out). If I have Windows 7 Professional SP1 and a Windows 7 RTM original? Do they change CD keys between service packs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can interchange them. You can use a given license key with any media, 32 or 64-bit, for the same type of installation. If you try to activate a retail disk with an OEM key, or vice-versa, you may need to call the Microsoft activation hotline to complete the process. Service packs do not affect activation of legal copies of Windows.